# Observed Beacon Committee Sizes

Tags: consensus, slots, epoch, beacon

It says here:  https://eth2book.info/capella/part2/building_blocks/aggregator/, that beacon committees are between 128 and 2048 members.  It's cool to know the bounds, but anyone have any actual data on how many we're seeing or where to get this information?